# wp_unregister_GLOBALS() in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, global, unset

The code below is from wordpress. Here are two things I don't understand:

```
/**
 * Turn register globals off.
 *
 * @access private
 * @since 2.1.0
 * @return null Will return null if register_globals PHP directive was disabled
 */
function wp_unregister_GLOBALS() {
if ( !ini_get( 'register_globals' ) )
    return;

if ( isset( $_REQUEST['GLOBALS'] ) )
    die( /*WP_I18N_GLOBALS_OVERWRITE*/'GLOBALS overwrite attempt detected'/*/WP_I18N_GLOBALS_OVERWRITE*/ );

// Variables that shouldn't be unset
$no_unset = array( 'GLOBALS', '_GET', '_POST', '_COOKIE', '_REQUEST', '_SERVER', '_ENV', '_FILES', 'table_prefix' );

$input = array_merge( $_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE, $_SERVER, $_ENV, $_FILES, isset( $_SESSION ) && is_array( $_SESSION ) ? $_SESSION : array() );
foreach ( $input as $k => $v )
    if ( !in_array( $k, $no_unset ) && isset( $GLOBALS[$k] ) ) {
        $GLOBALS[$k] = null;
        unset( $GLOBALS[$k] );
    }
}
```

First: how does  "$_REQUEST['GLOBALS']" overwrite the globals?
Second:

```
$GLOBALS[$k] = null;
unset( $GLOBALS[$k] );
```

Why set the $GLOBALS[$k] value null before unset it? Can i unset the $GLOBALS[$k] directly only?

Answer (score 2):

> First: how does "$_REQUEST['GLOBALS']" overwrite the globals?

This used to be possible in PHP with `register_globals` enabled. Due to that, sSetting `$_REQUEST["GLOBALS"]` could have led to the GLOBALS array being overwritten.

As to the double `unset()` and `null` call, it *might* have to do with what some people claim in the [comments to `unset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php): that `unset()` only removes the variable from the current scope, but doesn't necessarily immediately destroy it and free up the space allocated to it.

In that case, it would make sense to first "overwrite" the variable by setting it to null, then truly unsetting it. I don't know whether this is true, though.

Comment: thanks Pekka!the first question you may right, but the second one, in the manual it say: To unset() a global variable inside of a function, then use the $GLOBALS array to do...the value in the wp_unregister_GLOBALS function is a $GLOBALS value, then we also need set it to null ?

Comment: @steve as said, it may be a precaution to make sure the actual contents of the variable in memory are overwritten. But I don't know for 100% sure.